# How do you read an argument into an array

Tags: arrays, perl, command-line, passwords, arguments

I am not sure how to send the contents of an argument to an array. Say $ARGV[1] is a csv file. I want to read the contents of that file into an array in a perl script.

This is what I have tried

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

@array = <$ARGV[1]>;
print $array;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<$ARGV[1]>` doesn't work because `$ARGV[1]` is a string, not a file handle, and the `<>` operator must be used on file handles.

In the general case, you would resolve this by using `open`, but Perl has special magic for reading files provided in the command line.  Specifically, using `<>` by itself will return lines from files named on the command line, falling back to reading from `STDIN` if the command line doesn't mention any files.

So, to read the contents of all files named on the command line, it would simply be

```
my @array = <>;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read file by *second* command-line parameter you can use `$ARGV[1]`. But if you set filename in first parameter you should use `$ARGV[0]`. Then you should get a file handler by function `open` to read the file.

Work example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my (@array, $fh);
open($fh, '<', $ARGV[0]) or die('Can\'t open file ' . $ARGV[0]);
@array = <$fh>;
print @array;
```

PS. Also read [this](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-read-a-csv-file-using-perl) if you want to parse csv fields

Comment: Thanks. That link about parsing csv fields is just what i needed